# How to run Command Line Tool using AppleScript in Mac Application

Tags: objective-c, macos, command-line, applescript, keychain

I am working on MAC Application in which i have to store Password and SharedSecretKey in SYSTEM Keychain.

Now I added command line as Target in my current os x application and simply call VPNKeychain Class's method which is used to store password and sharedsecretkey in SystemKeychain.

how do I use applescript with admin privilege to call the command line tool with parameters.
Below is my code of command line tool.

```
#import "VPNKeychain.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        // insert code here...
        NSLog(@"Hello, World!");
        if (argc>0) {
            [VPNKeychain createPasswordKeyChainItem:@"L2TP By Mac Application" forService:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:argv[0]] withAccount:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:argv[1]] andPassword:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:argv[2]]];
            [VPNKeychain createSharedSecretKeyChainItem:@"L2TP By Mac Application" forService:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:argv[0]] withPassword:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:argv[3]]];
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Summary** : How can i call applescript from objective c class with admin privilege and call command line tool with parameters.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you can configure xcode to run scripts in build process. in the left bar click on your project, then in the center window select "Build Rules" and then in the upper left corner of this window "Custom". Now you can add a script file or directly enter your apple script code.